# Security company must aquire more guard dogs.

Tags: combinatorics

Could someone please check my work? Thanks.

> A security company needs to purchase guard dogs, and the kennel has four different breeds on-hand: German Sheppards, Pitbulls, Dobermann, and Rottweilers. If the company acquires twelve dogs, how many different selections of twelve dogs can the company make keeping in mind that the kennel only has two Rottweilers? (assume the kennel has al least twelve dogs of each bread of German Sheppards, Pitbulls, and Dobermann).

no. German Shepherds=12

no. Pitbulls=12

no. Dobermanns=12

no. Rottweiler=2

total dogs=38

to be selected=12

${38 \choose 12}=2707475148$

Comment: I think that by 'different selections', it is meant 'different combinations of dog breeds' There are many ways to take 6 pitbulls and 6 dobermanns, but I think all of those would count as the same

Comment: choosing 12 dogs from 38 necessarily includes selections of 12 Rottweilers, so you've failed to properly account for there only being 2 Rottweilers available.

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3665780/kid-in-a-candy-store)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they care about individual dogs, you are right. They are a company however, and hence only care about what kind of dog breed works for them.

Let us consider the following three possibilities separately.

1. They take no rottweilers
2. They take one rottweiler
3. They take two rottweilers

In the first case, they can pick any number $0 \leq n \leq 12$ for the amount of german sheppards. Then they have $12-n$ options for the amount of pittbulls, and the number of dobermanns is fixed by these previous two. Hence, the total number of possibilities is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{12} (12-n) = 12 \cdot 13 - \frac{12 \cdot 13}{2} = 6 \cdot 13 = 78 $$

In the second case, we make a similar reasoning to find
$$\sum_{n=0}^{11}(11-n) = 11 \cdot 12 - \frac{11 \cdot 12}{2} = 6 \cdot 11 = 66$$
possibilities

In the third case, there are
$$\sum_{n=0}^{10}(10-n) = 10 \cdot 11 - \frac{10 \cdot 11}{2} = 5 \cdot 11 = 55$$

The total number of different combinations is then $78+66+55 = 199$.

Comment: This is not correct. In the first case, you have $13-n$ options for the number of pitbulls. If you take $11$ of the first breed, you have $13-11=2$ options: take one or take none. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3665780/kid-in-a-candy-store), which has the correct result.